# Warum "in der Nacht" aber "am Tag"?

Tags: preposition

Warum da "in der" und dort "am"? Würde mich freuen über eine Erklärung.

Comment: _die Nacht_, _der Tag_??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Warum dann nicht *an der Nacht* und *im Tag*?

Comment: Note that Nacht seems to be the exception here: Am Morgen, am Mittag, am Abend

Comment: Morgen, Mittag, Abend are associated with _points_ in time; Nacht is more the concept of a time range. For example 'Am Wochenende', but 'In der Woche', and 'In den Ferien'.

Comment: @Olafant genau, das ist meine Frage. Warum die unterschiedlichen Präpositionen.

Comment: Es gibt keine Erklärung. Vor noch nicht allzu langer Zeit hieß es noch "bei der Nacht", und ich würde wetten, daß man keine logische Veränderung der Welt zwischen diesen Zeitpunkten finden kann, die das rechtfertigt.

Comment: Mit dem Versuch, eine solche Frage zu beantworten, könnte man viele Seiten füllen, ohne einer definitiven Antwort näher zu kommen und ohne dass es irgendeinen praktischen Wert hat.

Comment: @sermonionx: Bitte in Betracht ziehen, die Klärung/Präzisierung aus den Kommentaren mit in die Frage reinzunehmen. Eine präzisere Frage kann besser beantwortet werden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL/DR**: it's arbitrary.  Some parts of the paradigma may have reasonable systematicity, but that can be accidental or folk etymology.

---

Expressions for points in time pretty universally use locative expressions, because location is used so often as metaphor for time.

Which specific kind of locality is applied for each individual expression will depend originally on how the expression is constructed mentally (e.g., as a point or an interval, as mentioned in the comments).  But many can be constructed in multiple ways, so what remains in use is only what got conventionalized in the end.

For example, standard German uses *in der Nacht*, and you could say that's because "night" is an interval.  In Austrian, there's also the expression *auf d'Nacht* "in the evening" consistent with this.  But then, why is is *am Tag*, and not *im Tag*? *In den Ferien* but *am Wochenende*?  One of them just won.  Even more curious is *unter* (*unterm Tag*, *unter der Woche* for "during").

This problem is shared by many languages that have different locality notions.  Cf. *on the weekend*, *in December*, *on Monday*, *at night*.   Or Finnish *yö-llä*/*päivä-llä* "on night/day", *maanantai-na* "in Monday" (now that can be literally "as Monday", but the *-na* case is a historic locative preserved in this construction), *joulukuu-ssa* "in December".

---

Note: I am trying to answer the *why* here. *How* it works, i.e., what synchronic systematicity exists, is a different question, and I'd welcome input from people with more Germanistic or DAF knowledge.

Comment: Warum Englisch? Lol

Comment: Ups. Tut mir leid, das war ganz automatisch und ist mir echt nicht aufgefallen.